# Can't add a view to an existing subview in storyboard programatically

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiscrollview, swift2

I'm trying to simulate this view hierarchy in code:

```
 "scene"
    "view Shop Main"                       -> `UIView`
        "view shop scroll"                 -> `UIScrollView`
            "ViewDetail"                   -> `UIView`
                "Shop Connected Container" -> `UIView`
                    "Connected Shop"       -> `UIView`
```

I want to instantiate multiples "Connected Shop" and add them to "Shop Connected Container"
So like this:

```
"scene"
    "view Shop Main"                       -> `UIView`
        "view shop scroll"                 -> `UIScrollView`
            "ViewDetail"                   -> `UIView`
                "Shop Connected Container" -> `UIView`
                    "Connected Shop"       -> `UIView`
                    "Connected Shop"       -> `UIView`
                    "Connected Shop"       -> `UIView`
```

How can I do this programatically??
I have a custom class for each subView and a xib file as well. 
This is how I'm instantiate the subviews from the code:

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {

  /*1*/         let vShopMain = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("viewShopMain", owner: self, options: nil).first as! viewShopMain
    /*2*/       let vShopScroll = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("viewShopScroll", owner: vShopMain, options: nil).first as! viewShopScroll

    /*3*/       let vDetail : UIView = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("viewDetail", owner: vShopScroll, options: nil).first as! viewDetail
//
//
    /*4*/       let sConContainer : UIView = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("shopConnectedContainer", owner: vDetail, options: nil).first as! shopConnectedContainer
   /*5*/        let cShop = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("connectedShop", owner: sConContainer, options: nil).first as! connectedShop


        cShop.bannerTitle.text = "Shop Title"

        vShopMain.addSubview(vShopScroll)
        vShopScroll.addSubview(vDetail)
        vDetail.addSubview(sConContainer)
        sConContainer.addSubview(cShop)


        self.view.addSubview(sConContainer)
```

Also tried this with the exact same result:

```
        let vShopMain = UINib(nibName: "viewShopMain", bundle: nil).instantiateWithOwner(nil, options: nil)[0] as! viewShopMain

       let scroll = UINib(nibName: "viewShopScroll", bundle: nil).instantiateWithOwner(nil, options: nil)[0] as! viewShopScroll

        let vDetail = UINib(nibName: "viewDetail", bundle: nil).instantiateWithOwner(nil, options: nil)[0] as! viewDetail

        let sConContainer = UINib(nibName: "shopConnectedContainer", bundle: nil).instantiateWithOwner(nil, options: nil)[0] as! shopConnectedContainer

        let cShop = UINib(nibName: "connectedShop", bundle: nil).instantiateWithOwner(nil, options: nil)[0] as! connectedShop

        cShop.bannerTitle.text = "hola"

        vShopMain.addSubview(scroll)
        scroll.addSubview(vDetail)
        vDetail.addSubview(sConContainer)
        sConContainer.addSubview(cShop)


        self.view.addSubview(sConContainer)
```

But the "new" views added are below the other view, which is not the intended behavior, since I'm instantiating existing views from storyboard, not creating new ones.

I'm following the order of the storyboard hierarchy. Also the views are linked with their custom classes, and they have their xib files. But when I run my app I got this weird issue

What am I doing wrong here? Please help

Comment: `view's custom classes area assigned in storyboard` thats enough, now the view will be automatically loaded when corresponding controller is instantiated. you can create an outlet of whatever view you needed in controller class and use it. No need to load it programmatically load using `loadNibNamed `

Comment: yes, the view will be created. But I want to set the number of views programatically, so it can be 1 or it can be 10. I need to instantiate this view a number of times to create more than one. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Help you to figure out why its crashing. `loadNibNamed` returns an array of objects not a single view. So this will definitely crash

```
let vShopScroll = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("viewShopScroll", owner: self, options: nil) as! viewShopScroll
```

since you are assuming it returns `viewShopScroll` and forcefully unwrapping it. As you said your first line is working since there you taking the `first` object

```
let vShopMain = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("viewShopMain", owner: self, options: nil).first as! viewShopMain
```

Do the same for all other cases as well

Comment: So I'm doing this, but it's also crashing: 

let vShopScroll = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("viewShopScroll", owner: vShopMain, options: nil).first as! viewShopScroll

Comment: what the crash log says?

Comment: Could not cast value of type 'yuApp.viewShopMain' (0x10a2fcf50) to 'yuApp.viewShopScroll' (0x10a2faf30).